# How should I define a recurring HTML element & find them all with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to work out the best way to define a certain element, which is present an arbitrary number of times throughout a page, without requiring:

- the 'name' attribute; or
- definition of a new element (XHTML).

I am essentially after the 'name' attribute; however, it appears redundant, obsolete and depreciated in parts.

I am hoping to isolate and manipulate said elements using JavaScript, and preferably avoiding jQuery. Is there a reasonable solution?  So far I've thought of:

- iterating through all elements with a certain tag and checking for a specific className; or
- using incremental IDs on the elements (e.g. *el1*, *el2*, *el3*) and iterating through the sequence until getElementById returns null (feels botchy and only sort of what I'm after).

Thanks :)

Comment: The `name` attribute is neither redundant nor deprecated when used appropriately, but it does not strictly apply to every element. If it does apply to the element you have in mind, it seems to me the best choice.

Comment: Use a class: `document.querySelectorAll('.some-class')`

Comment: Why are we recommending QSA when gEBCN is about a [zillion times faster](http://jsperf.com/the-speed-of-selectors-with-tag-names/6) (except in Opera apparently)?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and posts - very interesting.  I've now got a decent solution using gEBCN.

Comment: @c24w be aware that gEBCN wasn't supported in "certain browsers" until recently. Take a look around for a "getElementsByClassName shim" ... the shim runs at a speed comparable to QSA (slower than native gEBCN, but tolerable).

Comment: Thanks again, I'll be sure to look into that.  Meanwhile, I found these handy pages :) [QSA](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) & [gEBCN](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname).

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

You can use `querySelectorAll`, and this is an example you can run in javascript console on this page.

```
var myList = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var c= 0 ; c < myList.length; c += 1) {
   console.log(myList[c]);
    myList[c].onmouseover= function () {alert(this)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your reference to a className is deliberate, you could use `document.getElementsByClassName()`, though this isn't supported by IE 8 and earlier. You could fall back on one of your other techniques for those versions. FWIW, I believe this is how jQuery does it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use **className** - `document.getElementsByClassName()`
2. In HTML 5 you can use **data** attribute - `document.querySelectorAll('[...]');`